# Can you merge a new contact with an existing experience contact

Tags: contact, user, merge, experience-cloud, identity-provider

Can you merge a new contact with an existing experience contact where the contact on the experience user get replaced by the new contact.

I understood that it is not possible to update the contact on the user but cant find if this could be possible with merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your ask - **the answer is no**. A new contact (with no experience user) can not replace an existing contact on their experience user when they're merged. You can easily test this yourself, the following happens

- Master contact record exists with no experience user (still need to enable)
- Deleted contact record (with experience user) has their user deactivated.

In the situation where both contacts have *active* experience users, the following occurs:

- Master contact record's user is active and pointing to the same contact it did originally
- Deleted contact record's user is deactivated.

Likewise, it's important to note the master contact record's user will retain its status. In the situation where both contacts are merged, but the master record's user was originally *inactive* and the deleted record's user was *active*:

- Master contact record's user stays inactive
- Delete contact record's user is deactivated

1. [Considerations for Merging Duplicate Contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.contacts_considerations_for_merging_duplicates.htm&type=5)

> In both Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic, **the primary contact
> must be associated with a portal user**. **The merged contact retains the
> portal user status of the primary contact.** If a non-master contact is
> associated with a portal user, that user is deactivated.

2. [Considerations for Merging Contacts Associated with Portal Users](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.contacts_merging_contacts_associated_with_portal_users.htm&type=5)

> - **You can merge a portal contact with another portal contact.**
> - You can
>   merge Customer Community enabled person accounts with Customer
>   Community Plus person accounts.
> - Before you merge contacts that include
>   partner users and customer users, decide which type of portal user to
>   retain. The user that you don’t retain is disabled. However, after the
>   contacts are merged, you can enable the contact for access to the
>   portal from which it was removed during the merge process.
> - You can
>   merge contacts that are associated with various accounts by
>   transferring the contacts that you want to merge into one account and
>   then merging the contacts that are associated with the common account.

Comment: Since english is not my native language the doc says:  The merged contact retains the portal user status of the primary contact. Is this only status active but contactID is replaced with new contactID on user or by no means can the contactID be replaced on the user after merge. Just wanted to have a clear understanding. Thanks for your explanation so far.

Comment: It's saying the winning record's user status dictates this. Think of a scenario where both contact's have an experience user. The master contact's user was inactive, but the merged contact's user was active. In this case, the master contact's user will stay inactive (the merged contact retains the user status of the primary contact).